# Submit GCP POST form without changing page

Tags: javascript, c#, jquery, post, google-cloud-print

I have a C# MVC website and I'm trying out Google Cloud Print(GCP) to print.

Google Provides this example
https://developers.google.com/cloud-print/docs/appDevGuide

```
<form action="https://www.google.com/cloudprint/submit" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="submitForm">
  <input type="hidden" name="xsrf" value="xsrfTokenHere"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="printerid" value="123456789"/>
  <input type="hidden" name="ticket" value='{"version": "1.0", "print": {}}'/>
  <input type="text" name="title" value="My Document"/>
  <input type="text" name="contentType" value="application/pdf"/>
  <input type="text" name="tag" value=""/>
  <input type="file" name="content"/>
  <input type="submit" value="Print"/>
</form>
```

Which does what it should. 
But it sends the user to the Google website were it displays the JSON response.

Is there any way to skip this last part, e.g let the user submit the form without moving to the google website.

I've tried various jQuery AJAX and similar calls. I've also tried posting the form inside of an iframe but none of these work since Google does not allow Cross-Origin calls.

If there was a way to post this either in HTML, Javascript or C# without jumping to the google result page it would've been great.